# How do i change the language of Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, language, language-pack

I have my laptop given to me from a Japanese friend. It has Japanese version genuine Windows 7 installed in it. I want to change the interface language to English or if possible the whole system language to English.

I want to avoid installing the english version again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows 7 Home Premium, you will need to upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate, to change whole system language (windows, menus, etc, to english). :/

Answer (score 0):

[Check out the instructions here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/28/change-display-language-for-windows-7-ui-welcome-screen-system-and-new-accounts/), depending on your version of Windows 7 you can use these guidelines to change your system language.